# Where to find industry funded PhDs?

Tags: phd, research-process, funding

In the fields of Mathematics and computer sciences, what are possible options to do a well funded PhD? In Canada or the US.

Is it better than doing a PhD as a part time student, while taking a job ?

I heard that one can find some opportunities in applied mathematics, in which case if the student is interested in pure mathematics, or computer science, can he just finish working on the required research to find time to do his own?
(I always considered applied mathematics easy, and not a science in its own right, like physics or mathematics).

Comment: Your question is best answered on Mathematics stack excahnge